# What legal limits are there on large scale population genetic capture and analysis?

Tags: medical, any-jurisdiction, personal-information

[A recent paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41559-023-02056-2) speculates that it is currently possible to capture human genetic material from the environment in a way that individuals can be identified and their genetics analysed.

> Inadvertent human genomic bycatch and intentional capture raise beneficial applications and ethical concerns with environmental DNA
>
> Additionally, high-quality human eDNA could be intentionally recovered from environmental substrates (water, sand and air), holding promise for beneficial medical, forensic and environmental applications. However, this also raises ethical dilemmas, from consent, privacy and surveillance to data ownership, requiring further consideration and potentially novel regulation.
>
> Even with no targeting or enrichment, our MinION shotgun sequencing was able to identify the genetic ancestry within pooled human populations and to identify variants associated with disease susceptibility. The long eDNA reads sequenced here suggest that with targeted enrichment of informative genomic locations, one could achieve individual-level identification even from pooled samples.

What regulations around the world would limit the collection and analysis of this data?  I think within the EU/UK the GDPR would put heavy and possibly insurmountable restrictions on this, but is there anything else, perhaps stronger and more explicit?  What about other countries?